# Percona server initial install PID file

Tags: mysql, config, percona

When I run `apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6`, the percona server gets installed and started. The processes running (`ps -ef | grep mysql`) look like this (HOSTNAME is obfuscated):

```
root     14309     1  0 23:54 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.pid
mysql    14413 14309  3 23:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.pid
```

My question is where is this default PID file coming from? There is no `my.cnf` file under `/etc/mysql` and the `my.cnf` file under `/usr` doesn't have any of this information. This is causing a problem ebcause when I deploy my configuration file and try to restart the server, the box obviously doesn't work. I believe the correct default for the PID file is `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is being set in the init mysql file.